# Angular auto assign drop down

Tags: angular, list, dropdown

I have a drop down angular select tag here. The drop down wont be selected when value being assign .

```
<select [(ngModel)]="controlType" #ctrl="ngModel" class="form-control" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
    <option [value]="undefined" selected>SILA PILIH</option>
    <option *ngFor="let alertControl of alertControlList" [ngValue]="alertControl">{{ alertControl?.desc }}
    </option>
</select>
```

**controlType** value from DB

```
{
    "errorCode": null,
    "errorMessage": null,
    "id": "b9e86e1a-cabc-11e8-9257-31ce15c52e16",
    "createdBy": "a6ef4d81-744e-49e7-9e1d-ab74a14935d6",
    "lastModifiedBy": "a6ef4d81-744e-49e7-9e1d-ab74a14935d6",
    "createdDate": 1538977256000,
    "lastModifiedDate": 1538977256000,
    "deleted": null,
    "active": true,
    "version": 0,
    "code": "1",
    "desc": "why"
}
```

**alertControlList value**

```
[{
    "code": "2",
    "version": "0",
    "desc": "why",
    "id": "b9e8bc3b-cabc-11e8-9257-31ce15c52e16",
    "HEX(id)": "B9E8BC3BCABC11E8925731CE15C52E16"
}, {
    "code": "1",
    "version": "0",
    "desc": "why",
    "id": "b9e86e1a-cabc-11e8-9257-31ce15c52e16",
    "HEX(id)": "B9E86E1ACABC11E8925731CE15C52E16"
}]
```

It's only work when i do a object mapping here . Any other simpler solution?

```
for (let int i = 0; i < alertControlList.length; i++) {
    if (alertControlList[i].code === dropdown.code) {
        console.log('do MATCH' + i + ' code' + dropdown.code);
        controlType = alertControlList[i];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `[selected]="alertControl.code === dropdown.code"` instead.

Comment: anything i can do it from html side ? so it will select the value?

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't work directly since you are setting your `option` value to an object and the `ngModel` does not match that value so it will not show as selected. Instead. You also seem to be using both `ngModel` with two-way binding and `ngModel` with `ngForm`. Use either one. If you are using `ngForm` to get the form values, you can set the value on `select` using `value` and change the `option` value to a unique property within `alertControl` like `code`.

```html
<select #ctrl="ngModel" [value]="controlType.code" class="form-control">
    <option *ngFor="let alertControl of alertControlList" [value]="alertControl.code">{{ alertControl?.desc }}</option>
</select>
```